# How do I keep CKEditor from setting the form field automatically?

Tags: ckeditor

We are tying to get CKEditor 4 to NOT update the text area that it is attached to.

We simply want to get the data out of the editor, add some extra text to it and then submit it in the field.

The problem is that CKEditor is overriding the submit function to update the field with the text of the editor at the last minute.

How do I stop CKEditor from updating the form field automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the [`config.autoUpdateElement`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-autoUpdateElement) to `false`.

Or instead of using `CKEDITOR.replace` use `CKEDITOR.appendTo`.